# Речевые ошибки в ЕГЭ по русскому языку: называние писателей по имени-отчеству

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, стилистика, ономастика, егэ

Один из экспертов ЕГЭ, ведущий блог об экзамене по русскому языку в соцсети, сообщает, что использование в сочинении формулировок типа ***Александр Сергеевич*** в романе «Евгений Онегин»... является речевой ошибкой.

Является ли называние автора по имени-отчеству в действительности **речевой** ошибкой? (Ранее было принято считать, что она относится к разряду этических, -- верно ли и это?)

Comment: Здесь _этические_ ошибки именуют _особым видом речевых_: http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200701009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одно время "**этико-речевые**" ошибки (в значении *вульгаризации речи*) входили вторым пунктом в официальную классификацию **речевых** ошибок (Критерий 10):

https://down.ctege.info/ege/obshee/rus/teoriya+praktika/rus-C1-teoriya+praktika-10-klassifikatciya-rechevyh-oshibok.pdf

В современных рекомендациях к оценкам ЕГЭ (2018)

https://down.ctege.info/ege/2018/kriterii-fipi/rus2018kriterii-fipi.pdf

этого нет, но остался отдельный критерий **К11. Соблюдение этических норм** (по смыслу - отсутствие речевой агрессии). Едва ли можно подвести под него случай лёгкой фамильярности с Пушкиным. Но в классификации речевых ошибок К10 есть два "стилистических" пункта:

> 4. Употребление слов иной стилевой окраски (Автор, обращаясь к этой проблеме, пытается направить людей немного в другую колею.)
> 5. Неуместное употребление эмоционально-окрашенных слов и фразеологизмов (Астафьев то и дело прибегает к употреблению метафор и
>    олицетворений.)

Можно ли под это подвести наш пример - вопрос субъективный (думаю, при желании можно - тогда это и будет **речевая ошибка**).

Но специалистами не всегда делается различие между этикой (вопросы речевой агрессии) и речевым этикетом. Например в книге

> *Е.В. Михайлова ЕГЭ-2017. Русский язык. Алгоритм написания сочинения.
> М. 2016* есть такое предостережение. **Этически некорректно** называть
> писателя только по имени и отчеству. Например: "Александр Сергеевич
> считал..."
>
> https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=xpxmDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=o-ccSAOkwN&sig=ACfU3U1pdIVazkmjXfq7V0OgGXRFWyVYUA&w=1280

Поэтому, хотя формально **этических ошибок** больше "не существует", может случиться "несоблюдение этических норм".

Answer (score 3):

Это, скорее всего, больше этическая ошибка, потому что обращение "Александр Сергеевич" обладает личным оттенком и не вписывается в характер сочинения формата ЕГЭ. Вряд ли речевая. Но лучше избегать при написании ЕГЭ.

Comment: «Скорее всего... Вряд ли речевая. Но лучше избегать...» Это ответ или совет?